# apps.Facebook.com/XYZ vs. Facebook.com/XYZ/app_123456789

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

what's the difference between apps.Facebook and Facebook.com/COMPANY_NAME/app_1234567 ?

For example: http://www.facebook.com/AcademyofArtUniversity/app_307555419320340

I'm trying to build a similar contact form page for a client, but I when I create an app, I get apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME rather than the app name at the end.  Is there a difference?  Are these different types of apps, or is one just an older style name?

Bonus question: Why wouldn't Academy of Art (using the second step from their example above) request User permissions to pull in the Facebook Graph data rather than require users to re-enter it?  Is this related to my question above?  Is there a best practice around using Permissions vs. New Entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apps.facebook.com/[namespace]` is the primary url to a [Canvas app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/), while the latter, `www.facebook.com/[pagename]/app_[appid] is your app added to a page as a [Page tab app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/).

For the second question, this app probably doesn't want to ask for permissions (perhaps to lower the friction) since only a few fields would actually be accesible via the graph.

Comment: Thanks Sean, this is exactly what I wanted to know.